# Second Degree Third Order Non-linear ODE with Dependent Variable y Missing

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The ODE I am having trouble with is:$$Solve: (\frac{d^3y}{dx^3})^2 +x\frac{d^3y}{dx^3}-\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=0$$
The thing is that I'm not supposed to know non-linear ODEs yet. So, I'm supposing this has to be made linear somehow. I just don't understand how I should convert this into a degree-1 ODE. Help?

Comment: Hint: Substitute $y''=u(x)$ as a new function. Then there are ways to make the problem linear, but start with that

Comment: @YuriyS I have to do this using a missing dependent variable approach.

Comment: @YuriyS Done. Hints on how I can now make it linear?

Comment: See for future reference Clairaut differential equation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clairaut%27s_equation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**hint**

If we differentiate, we find

$$2y^{(4)}y^{(3)}+xy^{(4)}=0$$
$$=y^{(4)}\Bigl (2y^{(3)}+x\Bigr) $$

Comment: But isn't this still non-linear?

Comment: I got it finally!

Answer (score 1):

substitute $$\frac{d^2y(x)}{dx^2}=u(x)$$ then we get
$$u(x)=\left(\frac{du(x)}{dx}\right)^3+x\frac{du(x)}{dx}$$
differentiate both sides with respect to $x$
$$\frac{du(x)}{dx}=x\frac{d^2u(x)}{dx^2}+\frac{du(x)}{dx}+3\left(\frac{du(x)}{dx}\right)^2\frac{d^2u(x)}{dx^2}$$
$$\frac{d^2u(x)}{dx^2}\left(x+3\left(\frac{du(x)}{dx^2}\right)^2\right)=0$$
and we have to solve
$$\frac{d^2u(x)}{dx^2}=0$$
or
$$x+3\left(\frac{du(x)}{dx}\right)^2=0$$

Comment: $u(x)=xu'(x)+u'(x)^2$ (note the square) is an often used example of a Clairaut equation with standard solution forms including a singular solutions and composite solutions that branch off from it.

Answer (score 1):

***A simple hint***

$$(y''')^2+xy'''-y''=0$$
Substitute $z=y''$
$$(z')^2+xz'-z=0$$
$$(z')^2+xz' +\frac {x^2} 4 -\frac {x^2} 4-z=0$$
$$(z'+\frac x2)^2 -\frac {x^2} 4-z=0$$
$$(z'+\frac x2)^2 -(z+\frac {x^2} 4)=0$$
Susbtitute $w=z+\frac {x^2} 4 \to w'=z'+\frac x2$
$$\boxed {(w')^2 -w=0}$$
It's easy to solve now